# Limit download speed using PHP

Tags: php, download, performance

I found on Google some PHP scripts to limit the download speed of a file, but the file download at 10 Mbps or if it download at 80 kbps as i set it, after 5 mb, it stops downloading.

Can some one tell me where I can found a good PHP download speed limit script please?

Thank you very much

--- Edit ---

Here is the code :

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
// change this value below
$cs_conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('shareit', $cs_conn);

// local file that should be send to the client
$local_file = $_GET['file'];
// filename that the user gets as default
$download_file = $_GET['file'];

// set the download rate limit (=> 20,5 kb/s)
$download_rate = 85; 
if(file_exists($local_file) && is_file($local_file)) {
    // send headers
    header('Cache-control: private');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($local_file));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$download_file);

    // flush content
    flush();    
    // open file stream
    $file = fopen($local_file, "r");    
    while(!feof($file)) {

        // send the current file part to the browser
        print fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024));    

        // flush the content to the browser
        flush();

        // sleep one second
        sleep(1);    
    }    

    // close file stream
    fclose($file);}
else {
    die('Error: The file '.$local_file.' does not exist!');
}




if ($dl) {
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable');
    die('Abort, you reached your download limit for this file.');
}
?>
```

Comment: you should use `echo` instead of `print`, it's slightly faster

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason your download stops after 5MB is because it takes over 60 seconds to download 5MB at 80KB/s. Most of those "speed limiter" scripts use `sleep()` to pause for a while after sending a chunk, resume, send another chunk, and pause again. But PHP will automatically terminate a script if it's been running for a minute or more. When that happens, your download stops.

You can use `set_time_limit()` to prevent your script from being terminated, but some web hosts will not allow you to do this. In that case you're out of luck.

Comment: If i put set_time_limit(0); at the begining of my script, it doesn'T limit the speed :S.. See original post for PHP code.

Comment: I don't see how using set_time_limit() would stop your script from limiting download speeds. All it should do is keep the script from timing out. The heart of your script is the sleep() function, which has nothing to do with set_time_limit().

Comment: I used set_time_limit cause after 60 seconds my download stop... :(

Comment: Keep in mind, while setting the set_time_limit(), the duration of sleep() will be ignored in the execution time.

Comment: @kijin "In that case you are out of luck" that's funny. have u stumbled upon an alternate solution to achieve speed limit in php

Answer (score 12):

A second is too much time, it will make clients think that the server is unresponsive and prematurely end the download.
Change `sleep(1)` to `usleep(200)`:

```
set_time_limit(0);

$file = array();
$file['name'] = 'file.mp4';
$file['size'] = filesize($file['name']);

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Description: file transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file['name'] . '"');
header('Content-Length: '. $file['size']);

$open = fopen($file['name'], 'rb');
while( !feof($open) ){
    echo fread($open, 256);
    usleep(200);
}
fclose($open);
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried my hand at a custom class that can help you deal with rate limiting downloads, you could try the following?

```
class Downloader {
     private $file_path;
     private $downloadRate;
     private $file_pointer;
     private $error_message;
     private $_tickRate = 4; // Ticks per second.
     private $_oldMaxExecTime; // saving the old value.
     function __construct($file_to_download = null) {
        $this->_tickRate = 4;
        $this->downloadRate = 1024; // in Kb/s (default: 1Mb/s)
        $this->file_pointer = 0; // position of current download.
        $this->setFile($file_to_download);
     }  
     public function setFile($file) {
        if (file_exists($file) && is_file($file))
           $this->file_path = $file;
        else 
           throw new Exception("Error finding file ({$this->file_path}).");
     }
     public function setRate($kbRate) {
        $this->downloadRate = $kbRate;
     }
     private function sendHeaders() {
        if (!headers_sent($filename, $linenum)) {
           header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
           header("Content-Description: file transfer");
           header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $this->file_path . '"');
           header('Content-Length: '. $this->file_path);
        } else {
           throw new Exception("Headers have already been sent. File: {$filename} Line: {$linenum}");
        }
     }
     public function download() {
        if (!$this->file_path) {
           throw new Exception("Error finding file ({$this->file_path}).");
        }
        flush();    
        $this->_oldMaxExecTime = ini_get('max_execution_time');
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
        $file = fopen($this->file_path, "r");     
        while(!feof($file)) {
           print fread($file, ((($this->downloadRate*1024)*1024)/$this->_tickRate);    
           flush();
           usleep((1000/$this->_tickRate)); 
        }    
        fclose($file);
        ini_set('max_execution_time', $this->_oldMaxExecTime);
        return true; // file downloaded.
     }
  }
```

I've hosted the file as a gist aswell on github here. - https://gist.github.com/3687527

Answer (score 1):

Downloader class is good but have one problem if you have two downloads at same time, you will lose `max_execution_time` value.

Some example:

Download first file(size = 1mb; download time 100 seconds )

After one second download second file ( size = 100 mb; dowload time = 10000 seconds)

First download set `max_execution_time` to 0

Second remeber `_oldMaxExecTime` as 0

First download end and return `max_execution_time` to old value

Second download end and return `max_execution time` to 0

Answer (score 0):

try this:
https://opengeo.tech/download-limiter-php/

using pv unix command for best for greater precision in the bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

First of all `max_execution_time` is the execution time of your script. Sleeping is not part of it.

Regarding speed limiting you could use something like a Token bucket. I've put everything into one convenient library for you: [`bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle`](https://github.com/bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle)

```
use bandwidthThrottle\BandwidthThrottle;

$in  = fopen(__DIR__ . "/resources/video.mpg", "r");
$out = fopen("php://output", "w");

$throttle = new BandwidthThrottle();
$throttle->setRate(100, BandwidthThrottle::KIBIBYTES); // Set limit to 100KiB/s
$throttle->throttle($out);

stream_copy_to_stream($in, $out);
```

Answer (score 0):

I plan on making a script that gives a differentiated answer to this question. I'm going to allow for acceleration as it becomes less and less a file. I can show you my math here and you can use it in the same way I do.

```
x=2
l = filesize/x
n = | current_tangent_point - %_finished |
m = l*2 + n*2
P = m
L0 = P/2
L1 = L0 + n/2
L1 is the first derived answer to the question
```

[image: This is as good as it gets]

Now plugin L1 for x

Divide the two answers first over the second

That's a perfect gradient of speed.

I even made that equation myself. I hope to get published one day.

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me

```
<?php

$file_to_download = '1.mp3';
$client_file = '1.mp3';

$download_rate = 200; // 200Kb/s

$f = null;

try {
    if (!file_exists($file_to_download)) {
        throw new Exception('File ' . $file_to_download . ' does not exist');
    }

    if (!is_file($file_to_download)) {
        throw new Exception('File ' . $file_to_download . ' is not valid');
    }

    header('Cache-control: private');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_to_download));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename=' . $client_file);

    // flush the content to the web browser
    flush();

    $f = fopen($file_to_download, 'r');

    while (!feof($f)) {
        // send the file part to the web browser
        print fread($f, round($download_rate * 1024));

        // flush the content to the web browser
        flush();

        // sleep one second
        sleep(1);
    }
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} finally {
    if ($f) {
        fclose($f);
    }
}
```