# Restrictions on file download speed?

Tags: php, download, rate-limiting

I am contemplating setting up a file host (mostly for the exercise) but how do you ensure that free users are only capable of 40-50 kb/s speed while premium users can go at faster speeds?

I guess you place all the files on 2 separate servers and simply control the port connection (10 Mbit vs. 1000 Mbit), but that would require a mirror harddisk setup.

With all the file hosts out there, I am betting there must be a simpler solution.

Comment: Edit: I think I found something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002106/limit-download-speed-using-php at least it seems to work (currently testing it with consistent 75 kb/s).

Comment: That is very cool, I like it.

Comment: In regards to the link I posted above, it is the bottom script on that page I am testing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12245044/1934039

Answer (score 1):

This would be something implemented at the web-server level. This question will probably cover how to implement the throttling if you're using apache: [How can I implement rate limiting with Apache? (requests per second)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131681/how-can-i-implement-rate-limiting-with-apache-requests-per-second)

As for doing it on a per-user basis there may be a way to interface with these apache configuration directives from php or you could just have two virtual hosts with one being locked down to certain users and with a higher throttle rate.

Comment: blank, added comment to original post

Answer (score 0):

You can directly control the bandwidth in PHP userland with e.g.
 [`bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle`](https://github.com/bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle)

```
use bandwidthThrottle\BandwidthThrottle;

$in  = fopen(__DIR__ . "/resources/video.mpg", "r");
$out = fopen("php://output", "w");

$throttle = new BandwidthThrottle();

if ($user->isPremium()) {
    $throttle->setRate(500, BandwidthThrottle::KIBIBYTES); // 500KiB/s
} else {
    $throttle->setRate(50, BandwidthThrottle::KIBIBYTES); // 50KiB/s
}

$throttle->throttle($out);

stream_copy_to_stream($in, $out);
```