# Limit User Downloads

Tags: php, .htaccess, download

I have a website which has multiple downloadable videos, Im after a way of limiting the amount of files any user can download at any one time, Currently all users can download all files at once, which is killing speed!

So need to limit to say x2 downloads at once! Is this done in the .htaccess or via php

Thanks

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002106/limit-download-speed-using-php) at restricting speed, as opposed to restricting the amount of files downloaded simultaneously.

Comment: UPDATE! I have added the MOD_BW to the apache server and yet to configure it , trying to find some help to do so

Answer (score -2):

In your download php script make a entry in database table when user hit download process.
As a number of count download hide download button.

Comment: and if the user aborts the download(s) by closing the browser?

Comment: He wants to limit the number of simultaneous downloads, not the total amount of downloads.

Comment: have not possible that track to cancel download.

Comment: Because if user hit download and cancel it after few minutes then it is not possible to track whole download process. You just do to track when  user start download successfully .

Comment: And for limit speed you can visit following link http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/dl-speed-limit.htm

Comment: Yes i want to limit simultaneous D/L's as its killing bandwidth and slowing the server down with so many connections.