# PHP file_put_contents set speed limit

Tags: php, file, curl, download

I try to download big file from url to my server, but I need to set download speed limit, for example 100kb/s.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $random = rand(00000000,999999999);
    $file_url = "BIG FILE URL";

    $get_name = basename($file_url);
    $file_new_name = $random.$get_name;

    $get_file = file_get_contents($file_url);
    $put_file = file_put_contents($file_new_name, $get_file);

    if( $put_file ){
        echo "Done!";
    }
?>
```

Code is working but fast speed! I need speed to be 100kb/s.

Comment: You can try this [(answer )](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31898795/2641347)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [mod_bandwidth](http://www.cohprog.com/mod_bandwidth.html) or more advanced [mod_cband](http://dembol.org/blog/mod_cband/).

Quote from mad_bandwidth site:

> `Mod_bandwidth` is a module for the Apache webserver that enable the
>   setting of server-wide or per connection bandwidth limits, based on
>   the directory, size of files and remote IP/domain.

Quote from `mod_cband` site:

> `mod_cband` is an Apache 2 module provided to solve the problem of
>   limiting users’ and virtualhosts’ bandwidth usage. The current
>   versions can set virtualhosts’ and users’ bandwidth quotas, maximal
>   download speed (like in `mod_bandwidth`), requests-per-second speed and
>   the maximal number of simultanous IP connections (like in
>   `mod_limitipconn`)

Here is tutorial about [how to use cband to limit download speed](http://blog.camilord.com/2012/06/13/manage-apache-download-speed-and-traffic-limits/).